# Pass multiple files to another class

Tags: java, file, dynamic

How to pass multiple files to another class?

I am developing an application which first compresses the image and after that it'll convert it into pdf.

The program which i have written works well seperately  ie; it compresses the image and then in another project i use the path where the image are stores to convert it to pdf.

Now i want to have both these codes in the same project and i am encountering the problem where i am creating a loop where i pass the path name one by one. The source path works well but i need to specify the destination path which changes the name dynamically this where i am facing the problem. I have attached the code below please tell me what to do.

```
        System.out.println("before convert");
        Conversion cc = new Conversion();
        File directory = new File(Success);
        File[] files = directory.listFiles();
        if(files!=null)
        {
            for(File f:files){
                String path = f.getName();
                System.out.println("The Name of file is="+path); 
                cc.createPdf("path" , "output", true);
                System.out.println("the file is ="+output+".pdf");
                System.out.println("after convert");
            }
        }
```

In the above code i need to change the output file name dynamically here cc.createPdf("path" , "output", true);

Comment: Can you please specify the problem you are facing? If you need to name the output file dynamically then what is the criteria you are looking for like adding date time stamp to it. Some specific naming convention which has some dynamic part to it.

Comment: "new File(Success);" -- what type is "Success"? It confuses me, that it is starting with upper case leading to think that it is a class. Which it clearly isn't - it must be a filename or URI?

Answer (score 0):

A simple implementation would be to keep a `counter` outside loop and **increment** it before appending it to `output` file name

```
        int counter = 0;
        for(File f:files){
            String path = f.getName();
            System.out.println("The Name of file is="+path); 
            counter++; //increment the counter
            cc.createPdf("path" , "output"+counter, true); // append it to output
            System.out.println("the file is ="+output+".pdf");
            System.out.println("after convert");
        }
```

For more robustness, `counter` can be replaced by [UUID generator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html#randomUUID%28%29), System time in milliseconds etc

Answer (score 0):

Im guessing your having trouble getting a File object with a newly created .pdf extension, you will have to adapt this to your code but it should be pretty straight forward.

```
File inputFile = new File("c:\\myimage.png");
String fileName = inputFile.getName();
File pdfFile = new File(inputFile.getParent(), fileName.substring(0, fileName.indexOf(".")) +".pdf");
System.out.println(inputFile + " " + pdfFile);
```

Comment: I think it should be `fileName.lastIndexOf(".")` because the path may have more than one dot.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should keep things simple by just appending ".pdf" to the names. The fact that you are processing a directory ensures that the source file names are unique. Hence, the new ".pdf" names would also be unique.

Assuming your output files land in the same directory, it also becomes much easier to sort files by names and know immediately which ".pdf" files correlate to which source files.

So, your output file name simply becomes

```
String path = f.getName();
String output = path.substring(0, path.lastIndexOf('.')) + ".pdf";
```